# Vue unit test third party dependency causes Reference Error

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js

I have a very basic vue component:

```
<script>

    export default {
        name: "testComponent",

        data() {
            return {
                 manageWaiting: new ManageWaiting()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I try to test it with mocha like this:

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {

    it('works', () => {

        let wrapper = mount(TestComponent);
    });
});
```

I get this error:
ReferenceError: ManageWaiting is not defined

Where should I import my ManageWaiting class?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'd import the class definition in the same file that uses it, so in your case, you should import the `ManageWaiting` class inside `TestComponent.vue`:

```
<script>
// TestComponent.vue
import { ManageWaiting } from './ManageWaiting'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      manageWaiting: new ManageWaiting()
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/71o1k2nz90)